# Is mongoose findOne guaranteed to return the latest inserted doc it finds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following in the database:

```
username: Murat1010
firstName: Murat
lastName: Paşa
city: İstanbul
createdAt: 2022-07-15T23:24:32.382+00:00

username: Ömer98
firstName: Ömer
lastName: Demir
city: İstanbul
createdAt: 2022-07-15T23:25:00.023+00:00


username: Yaser334
firstName: Yasser
lastName: Tayyar
city: İstanbul
createdAt: 2022-07-15T23:27:59.688+00:00
```

I have the following Mongoose code:

```js
const newestMember = await Users.findOne({city: "İstanbul"})
```

Is `newestMember` guaranteed to return Murat's Doc? guaranteed to return the newest one?
can I stick to findOne?
If it's not correct, then how?

Comment: If multiple documents satisfy the query, this method returns the first document according to the natural order which reflects the order of documents on the disk. In capped collections, natural order is the same as insertion order. If no document satisfies the query, the method returns null. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Comment: sort by datetime. 3rd argument in findOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not guaranteed.
Read [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)
I would do:

```
const newestMember = await Users.findOne({city: "İstanbul"}).sort({createdAt: -1})
```